# Montouch.dialog access elements individually causes error

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm wanting to style the cells that I get back from a JSON response. I'm able to loop through the elements but as soon as I try to style them I get the error below.

What am I missing?

!-- error

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

!-- code

```
string responseString = string.Empty;
        Uri uri = new Uri ("http://myhost/sample.json");
        HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest (uri);
        request.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse;
        var obj = JsonValue.Load (new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream())) as JsonObject;
        if (obj != null) {


            var root = JsonElement.FromJson (obj);
            var jsonSection = root["section-1"] as Section;

            UILabel headerLabel = new UILabel();

            headerLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            headerLabel.Opaque = false;
            headerLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Blue;
            headerLabel.HighlightedTextColor = UIColor.White;
            headerLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (22);
            headerLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(8,0,200,60);
            headerLabel.Text = jsonSection.Caption;

            jsonSection.HeaderView = headerLabel;

            Console.WriteLine("before");


            foreach (var elmList in jsonSection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test");



                var element = new StyledStringElement(elmList.ToString())
                {

                    TextColor = UIColor.Red,
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown,
                    Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator
                };

                jsonSection.Elements.Add(element);


            }



            var dvc = new DialogViewController (root, true);
            navigation.PushViewController (dvc, true);
        }



        response.Close ();
```

Comment: This is what I ended up with: `var i =0;
    foreach (var question in questionsElm) {
    var answerJson = objRoot["sections"][0]["elements"][i]["sections"][0]["elements"];
    var questionSection = new Section (""){           HeaderView = new UILabel(new RectangleF (0, 0, 80, 30)),
};        foreach (JsonObject jentry2 in answerJson) {          questionSection.Add (new PostNatalCustomRadioElement (jentry2["caption"].ToString(), "answers"));
}                section.Add (new CustomRootElement (question.question_title, new RadioGroup ("answers", -1)){        questionSection, 
});

i+=1;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify a foreach enumeration. Use a for loop instead and adjust the index

You are getting an error because of

```
 jsonSection.Elements.Add(element);
```

I don't know exactly what you're doing by this code (off the top of my head) should work:

```
 var tmpSection = new Section();
 foreach(var elmList in jsonSection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");

            var element = new StyledStringElement(elmList.ToString())
            {

                TextColor = UIColor.Red,
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown,
                Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator
            };

            tmpSection.Elements.Add(element);


        }

        jsonSection.Elements.AddRange(tmpSection); //it this doesn't work, loop through tmpSection and add the elements to jsonSection.
```